# Implementing MVC for Repeating Objects

Tags: model-view-controller

I have several objects and a "template" to display these objects in:

```
Name: $name
Description: $description
Price: $price
Picture: $image
```

Since the number of objects varies, how can I display these according to the MVC pattern? Should I wrap the template in a function and call it for each object?

Comment: Hello. Can you say please what kind of template do you have?? The language seems to be PHP but I don't understand what kind of template are you using.

Comment: @Jean It's not a traditional programming template in all its glory, more of "this data should be displayed this way" type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please yell at me if I'm misinterpreting the question, but if I'm not, I would create a class DisplayItem, and have it play as a model to plug the object data into, and hand the list or array of displayItems over to the View.